# docx4j how to convert embedded doc properties into simple text while converting docx to pdf

Tags: java, xml, pdf, converters, docx4j

I wanted to know how can I convert by docx4j a displayed doc property into "simple text". My document schema is as the following:

```
Full Name: [DOCPROPERTY] [DOCPROPERTY]
Date and Place of Birth: [DOCPROPERTY] [DOCPROPERTY]
```

The main issue is that when I convert my document into PDF, I loose the above information. Here's the code:

```
String inputfilepath = "...somePath"    
String outputfilepathWord = "...anotherPath"

WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new java.io.File(inputfilepath));
wordMLPackage.save(new File(outputfilepathWord));

FOSettings foSettings = Docx4J.createFOSettings();
foSettings.setWmlPackage(wordMLPackage);
OutputStream os = new java.io.FileOutputStream(outputfilepath);
Docx4J.toFO(foSettings, os, Docx4J.FLAG_EXPORT_PREFER_XSL);
```

and in the pdf converted I have the following structure:

```
Full Name: 
Date and Place of Birth:
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Use of FieldUpdater

```
FieldUpdater updater = new FieldUpdater(wordMLPackage);
updater.update(true);
```

catches the following exception:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.LinkedList.removeFirst(LinkedList.java:268)
at java.util.LinkedList.pop(LinkedList.java:799)
at org.docx4j.model.fields.FieldsPreprocessor.inParentResult(FieldsPreprocessor.java:214)
at org.docx4j.model.fields.FieldsPreprocessor.handleRun(FieldsPreprocessor.java:346)
at org.docx4j.model.fields.FieldsPreprocessor.handleContent(FieldsPreprocessor.java:180)
at org.docx4j.model.fields.FieldsPreprocessor.canonicaliseInstance(FieldsPreprocessor.java:142)
at org.docx4j.model.fields.FieldsPreprocessor.canonicalise(FieldsPreprocessor.java:128)
```

here:

```
else if (p.getParent() instanceof java.util.List) {
            // This does happen!
            index = ((java.util.List)p.getParent()).indexOf(p);
            P newP = FieldsPreprocessor.canonicalise(p, fieldRefs); //<<--EXCEPTION
            //log.debug("NewP length: " + newP.getContent().size() );
            ((java.util.List)p.getParent()).set(index, newP);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the ConvertOutPDF sample, you need:

```
    // Refresh the values of DOCPROPERTY fields 
    FieldUpdater updater = new FieldUpdater(wordMLPackage);
    updater.update(true);
```

Comment: You should log an issue, including a test case to replicate, at https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/issues

Comment: it seems that FieldUpdater crashes when encountering ":" into a docproperty value.

Comment: Interesting.  Did you log an issue containing a test case?

Comment: no I don't but you can try whatever kind of custom doc property you have, if you insert ":" inside the docproperty, fieldupdater will catch exception